# Read More is not working in query posts

Tags: query-posts, read-more

I have Query_posts in my page.
the posts have  tags to separate for read more,
But while doing query posts  it is pulling all content for `<?php the_content('read more..');?>`

Comment: have you considered the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#How_to_use_Read_More_in_Pages ?

Comment: what code you are implemented already?

Answer (score 3):

this is for the codex:

> Please remember that the "Read More" tag is used only on the Home page which shows the latest posts. It does not work in "Pages". If you want to turn it on in Pages too for showing a set of partial posts, use the following code inside the loop for the dynamic content:

```
<?php
global $more;
$more = 0;
?>
//The code must be inserted ahead of the call to the content

<?php the_content('Continue Reading'); ?>
```

So basically it means that you need to golbalize `$more` and set it to zero (0) before your query.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Retrieve_a_Particular_Post as Bainternet describes